# trying to use ng-class with multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm trying to set up an ng-class to work on a div with two conditions:

ng-class="(accounts.length == 1 && account.cardName =='Cash') ? 'one-dash-cash' : ''"

and

ng-class="(accounts.length == 1 && account.cardName =='Points') ? 'one-dash' : ''"

What's the best way to accomplish this? I've read that I shouldn't have all this logic in the HTML, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-class="{'one-dash-cash':accounts.length == 1 && account.cardName =='Cash','one-dash':accounts.length == 1 && account.cardName =='Points'}"
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the quick replies. 

But, aren't both of these answers the same thing? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a js map to `ng-class`.

```
<div ng-class="{
       'one-dash-cash':accounts.length == 1 && account.cardName =='Cash',
        'one-dash':accounts.length == 1 && account.cardName =='Points'
}"></div>
```

So based on the condition appropriate class will be applied to the element.

`ng-class` reference https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided by Shankar and user3227295 are correct and work correctly, but there are 2 alternate methods that you can use. I am not saying that they are better than the ones already mentioned, but it is better to be aware of them. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qngo1NFqu3LIaD8yON5E?p=preview) is a plunker showing all three approaches.

1. Put your logic in controller than inline (which I would use)

   ```
   $scope.isOneDash = $scope.accounts.length == 1 && $scope.account.cardName =='Points';
   $scope.isOneDashCash = $scope.accounts.length == 1 && $scope.account.cardName =='Cash';
   ```

And in your html

```
<div ng-class="{
       'one-dash-cash': isOneDashCash,
        'one-dash': isOneDash
    }">Hello</div>
```

2. Use an attribute directive. This may be an overkill for your case, but surely a way.

   ```
   app.directive('dashOrCash', function() {
     return {
   retrict: 'A',
   link: function(scope, elem) {
     if (scope.accounts.length == 1 && scope.account.cardName =='Cash') {
       elem[0].classList.add('one-dash-cash');
     }
     if (scope.accounts.length == 1 && scope.account.cardName =='Points') {
       elem[0].classList.add('one-dash');
     }
   }
     }})
   ```